# table function doesn't work for dates with date class - R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm curious why there is not a question even similar to this one (wondering if it's not working because of something in my R console, but it doesn't seem to be), but here is it. The data:

```
df <- structure(c("17532", "17577", "17579", "17593", "17599", "17599", 
"17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", 
"17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", 
"17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", 
"17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", 
"17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", 
"17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", 
"17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", 
"17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599", "17599"
), class = "Date")

table(df)
> .
> 2018-01-01 2018-02-15 2018-02-17 2018-03-03 2018-03-09 
>          0          0          0          0          0
```

Why could be it is not working?

**EDIT: Additional Information**

The formats of the dates above come from a previous transformation from character to date with `lubridate::as.Date()`. The name of the vector is `fecha` and here are a few raw-values of the character vector:

```
"1960-01-06 00:00:00+00:00" "1960-03-27 00:00:00+00:00" "1960-05-07 00:00:00+00:00"
```

The data is registered daily, so you can assume the time is `00:00:00+00:00` for every date.

And here is the code which the character vector was transformed to date:

```
df$fecha <- df$fecha %>% as.Date()
```

Comment: `Date`s are a little weird--and so is `table`. I'd just do `table(as.character(df))` and not worry about it too much.

Comment: Chris, what gave you a vector of dates in this format? I can't find a database or file-import method that tells you it's giving you legitimate a `Date`-class object but with an internal storage of `character`.

Comment: @r2evans, I added the information you are asking.

Comment: Isn't *lubridate*'s function`as_date` not `as.Date`? I similarly can't replicate this from raw data to the structure shown. It's an interesting question, but it would be nice to track down how this happened exactly.

Comment: While the `as.Date`-vs-`as_date` thing is odd, I also cannot reproduce this phenomenon with either of them or any other date-related function I know about. Further, going along with @Gregor's comment, while `Date`s are a little weird, I would never have expected this behavior ...

Comment: One interesting thing is that it *displays* as a date though no date operations seem to work (e.g., `df + 1` should work on dates). This is based on `print.Date` which calls `format.Date` which calls `as.POSIXlt.Date` which includes `.Internal(Date2POSIXlt(x))` which includes `x = coerceVector(CAR(args), REALSXP)` (in [`src/main/datetime.c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/3f4e46a2d39337e0bfac4ab5fc5035862034550c/src/main/datetime.c#L1193)). So for presentation the non-numeric dates here is somewhat masked by an internal attempt to convert to numeric.

Answer (score 2):

Dates are stored as integers, not characters as you have specified.

```
df <- as.Date(c(17532L, 17577L, 17579L, 17593L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 
        17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 
        17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 
        17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 
        17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 
        17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 
        17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 
        17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L, 17599L), origin = "1970-01-01")
table(df)
# df
# 2018-01-01 2018-02-15 2018-02-17 2018-03-03 2018-03-09 
#          1          1          1          1         58
```

To fix your example, you can do `table(as.Date(as.integer(df), origin = "1970-01-01"))`. 1970-01-01 is the origin for dates from R. Another common one is "12-30-1899" for excel, and "1753-01-01" for SQL Server.

As for the behavior you're experiencing, it looks like it correctly gets the print method labels for the dates, but then says 0 frequency for each because the character values don't *really* match those dates. That's just a guess though.

Comment: nice. what the letter L can make a difference :)

Comment: @Tjebo The `L` isn't necessary - remove all the Ls and this will wok just as well. They key difference is the lack of quotes, so the numbers are actually numbers, not strings.